# In for loop update statement has problems with pointer assignment in ansi c

Tags: c, for-loop, pointers, segmentation-fault, ansi-c

Assignment to pointer in the update section create a Segmentation fault. Why?

```
int vars[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};

int* var = NULL;
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(vars); i++, var = &vars[i]){
    printf("%d \n", *var);
}
```

I'm expecting that var has actual value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for` loop has an initialization expression, a condition, and an increment. The increment is run **after** the loop runs for the first time. In this case:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(vars); i++, var = &vars[i]){
```

`var` is only assigned to a non-null value **after** the loop runs **the first time**, at which point `printf("%f \n", *var);` results in a null dereference (undefined behavior, in this case a segmentation fault). In addition to that, `sizeof()` returns the number of bytes in an array, not the number of elements. This also would result in an out of bounds access as the loop terminates much later than it should, assuming `sizeof(int) > 1`.

Try putting `var = &vars[i]` in the condition statement, which runs **before** the first iteration instead of in the increment statement, which runs **afterwards**, and dividing `sizeof(vars)` by `sizeof(*vars)` to get the number of elements in the array instead of the number of bytes.

```
int vars[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};

int* var;
for(int i = 0; var = &vars[i], i < sizeof(vars)/sizeof(*vars); i++){
    printf("%d \n", *var);
}
```

Comment: is `...;var=&vars[i], i < sizeof(vars)/sizeof(*vars); ...` connected with an and or an or?

Comment: @ptiza_v_nebe Neither, it's connected with a [comma operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator).

Answer (score -1):

I think I have found myself at least some understanding. The main problem is that scope of var inside of for brackets is different as outside. Maybe it could be compared to lambdas with its possibility to capture variables.

Following code works as intent:

```
double vars[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
int var_size = sizeof(vars)/sizeof(vars[0]);

double* var = NULL;
int i = 0;
for(var = &vars[0]; i < var_size; var = &vars[++i]){
    printf("%f \n", *var);
}
```

Comment: "_The main problem is that scope of var inside of for brackets is different as outside._": It has nothing to do with scopes. You had two mistakes. One was using `sizeof(vars)` instead of `sizeof(vars)/sizeof(vars[0])` (whether you use a variable `var_size` or not is irrelevant) and the second mistake is explained in the other answer.